# Python: Pandas data-frame inside a function

Tags: function, pandas

I would like to call pandas dataframe values inside a function. A simplified example of my requirement is: "print the values of a  data frame using a (defined) python function"

Working example:

Defining a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(range(1,10))
```

Then I defined a function to print the values one by one:

```
def write(f,n1,n2):
    for n in range(n1,n2):
        print(n,f)
```

After that the function is called:

```
write(s.loc[n],3,8)
```

But this gives an error "name 'n' is not defined". Please help me to fix this.

Comment: What's the non-simplified version? Are you allowed to just pass the dataframe to the function and work directly on it? Otherwise, you'll have to describe what `sd` is supposed to do to work out how `write` should be returning/yielding values (or possibly calling `sd` itself)

Comment: Sorry Jon, it was not sd, but write (the same function). Edited.

Comment: And given your input `s` there - what is the expected output? It's somewhat confused by the fact you mention you want to print things from a dataframe, but only demonstrate a series

Comment: @Jon, the expected output is the values of the series (from 3 to 8). I just gave that series as an example of data-frame.

Comment: So - why wouldn't you use `s[3:8]` here?

Comment: @Jon, my actual requirement is not just printing, but to find the standard deviation of many huge dataframes. Hence I am defining a function, to avoid repeated steps.

Comment: How so? They're the range you're looping over to get the value...? It might help explain what you're really trying to do here... You should be avoiding looping where possible. Also, you haven't answered my first comment...

Comment: I am trying to define a function that finds the standard deviation of dataframes. It involves: Inputting the data-frame with required column number, summing each element, squiring, dividing with number of iterations, and finally finding the squire root.

Comment: And you're doing that because the builtin functions aren't sufficient?

Comment: I dont think there are built in functions for that !

Comment: So you can't start with [std](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.std.html) ?

Comment: @Jon, thank you very much for introducing "std". Seems like that would serve my purpose.

Comment: When you find yourself trying to do what you're doing - if it's a common thing one would want to do with data - it's probably already there... or... at the very least - the building blocks to get to what you want are... (plus they'll be fully tested and optimised to work far faster than anything you could do looping yourself)

Comment: True. Once again thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a little bit of mixup:

```
def write(f,n1,n2):
for n in range(n1,n2):
    print(f.loc[n])

write(s,3,8)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Kot, that was helpful. But the data-frames in my actual case has many columns, hence ".loc" is to be given outside the function (ie. while calling the function, not inside), in order to specify the column I need.

Comment: You could add a parameter for column and pass the list of columns. As a reminder, `loc` uses `.loc[rows, columns]` where `columns` can be a list of strings that are column names